# number_to_currency Removing the Decimal Point

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, number-to-currency

Is there any way to change the value in the display to the following:

$100.25 to 10025

Need this to be in this format to go through a payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [String.delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-delete) method:

```
"$100.25".delete("$.")
=> 10025
```